# Short story about a futuristic prison?

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I remember reading it in a collection of stories it's about a poet who is put in a prison where they put a microchip in the inmates brains and if they try to leave it makes them feel intense pain. The protagonist eventually escapes and goes to a doctor to get the chip removed but he gets captured again and the doctor is also imprisoned with him.

I remember the book also had "a sound of thunder" in it as well if that helps.

Also another one of the stories in the book involved a supercomputer name thunder which had enslaved humanity by giving creating a matrix style paradise but was slowly falling apart and people were waking up.

Comment: About how long ago did you read it?

Comment: A few years ago but I think the book that the short story was in was published around the 80's

Comment: Do you remember what the crime was?

Comment: Here is a [list of collections](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?61488) containing "A Sound of Thunder"; click into a title and see the table of contents. Here are [the covers](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/titlecovers.cgi?61488); anything look familiar?

Comment: Sorry the details are a little vague but I remember it was something to do with speaking out against the government or some kind of protest.

Comment: I've been searching through but nothing seems to be ringing any bells yet thanks for the help though I'll keep checking maybe I missed one.

Comment: I think the name of the last story was "The Voice of Thunder," although since that name has been used for a large number of works, I can't find it via Google.  I read it in a 1970s anthology of young adult SF, and it was the only story that made a particular impression on me.  Near the end, it had this remarkable line (I paraphrase):  "I have been eighteen years old for centuries now.."

Answer (score 13):

It was '[The Winner](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?62544)' by Donald Westlake, collected in 1973's [**Science Fiction, edited by Sylvia Z. Brodkin**](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?29072) alongside Bradbury's 'A Sound of Thunder'.

> Not very far in the future at all, political prisoners have been
> implanted with a small black box that causes them to feel unbearable
> pain if they venture too far away from a signal transmitted inside
> their unwalled and mainly unguarded prison.  It’s a pilot program,
> that may soon be used in all prisons, for all crimes.
>
> A poet has been imprisoned for unknown crimes.   He refuses to accept
> his imprisonment, and tells the warden (named Wordman) so, before he
> walks out into the field surrounding the prison, in ever greater
> agony, until he collapses.  His screams can be heard from the warden’s
> office.  Wordman feels every scream in his soul, but he wants the poet
> to learn his lesson.  Then the screams stop.  They search for the
> poet.  They do not find him.
>
> The poet was picked up by a farmer, who not understanding what was
> going on, took him to a doctor, who does understand what is happening,
> and thoroughly disapproves.  He removes the black box.   But by then
> the authorities have found them, and both are now imprisoned, with
> black boxes inside of them.  The poet says he’s sorry.  The doctor
> says not to be.  At their earliest opportunity, they both intend to go
> walking into that field again, together.  Wordman thinks they’re both
> insane.  But the madness may be catching.

> <sub><sup>https://thewestlakereview.wordpress.com/category/donald-westlake-short-stories/</sup></sub>

Comment: Congratulations! Please accept your answer when the system lets you (generally 48 hours after you'd submitted it).

Comment: Was this made into an TV episode I wonder.  I swear I have watched something like this on TV at some point.